# Which tool/library is best suited to sync data without a central repository

Tags: java, git, synchronization, distributed

I am developing a Java app where several computers need to keep some a data file in sync. I cannot use a central repository, and I would like to use an existing system that does the synchronization rather than write my own.

I have been thinking of Git, as it is one of the version control systems that is distributed and can work without a central repository. (SVN is out of question since it depends on a central repo).

The computers will talk to each other via a messaging system such as JMS, using which they will keep the data in sync.

Is using Git a good idea? Is there a better method? Is it possible to easily plug in Git with my Java code, so that it works transparently to the user?

[EDIT: giving some more details of my requirements.]

There are three computers A, B, C which are somehow able to talk to each other (i.e., send strings to and receive strings from each other). This communication ability is outsourced and I am given `read` and `write` operations for this. The computers may not use standard protocols such as TCP but the bottomline is that the `read` and `write` functions work as required - transferring a string from one point to another.

The computers may not be online all the time.

I now want to hook up GIT or some other file sync tool so that I can keep a particular directory on A, B, C synchronized. I am inclined to use GIT because it is fast and does not require an omnipresent central server. However, I will need GIT to communicate over my `read` and `write` methods rather than use the TCP/IP stack that it normally does.

Can anyone provide some hints on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think I found the best way. Using GIT with bundles. http://progit.org/2010/03/10/bundles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to suggest a solution without detailed knowledge of your requirements, but have you checked out [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)? It has distributed implementations of a lot of the Java collections. It works over a multicast network and requires pretty much zero setup.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am checking out Hazelcast right now.